# Serve static files (JavaScript) with Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, static-resource, serving

I want to put some JavaScript files in one of my packages and make Struts serve them like `/struts/js/foo.js`

Struts does that for files in 'template' package (that's where jQuery plugin's files are located, guarded by `struts.ui.templateDir` option). However I want to put those files into another package; If I redefine `struts.ui.templateDir` then struts ceases working because it can't find its templates.

So the question is: How to tell Struts to serve files in `org.foo.some.package.js` as `/struts/js/whatever.js`?

Comment: Have you seen this link: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/static-content.html?

Comment: @AleksandrM nice, didn't know that. You're a good candidate for the bounty if you care to write a full answer.

Comment: why not to use some web-server for this? say Apache or nigix which is much better and efficient way to serve static contents

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi not if you want to serve content from inside .jar files, handy for internal admin pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Struts2 can serve static content out of the box. By default static content is being served by `DefaultStaticContentLoader` an implementation of `StaticContentLoader`. It automatically  searches the following packages:

- org.apache.struts2.static
- template
- static
- org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging

You can add additional packages to be searched in filter init parameter named "packages".

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>packages</param-name>
        <param-value>some.package another.one</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

You can add more than one package, use comma or space or tab or new line as separator.

BTW you can control whether static content is being cached by a browser or not with this constant:

```
struts.serve.static.browserCache
```

Comment: How did they manage to have packages named static? It's a reserved word :-/

Comment: @alamar: Well, it is for static resources after all. So there is no source files in it.

Comment: @alamar It's not the bare word `static` (nor does it refer to a method or field name). There are other exceptions for "reserved words", for example you could have `String staticWord = "Hello";`.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to extend the entire template & change the templateDir as you already suggested. Unless one needs to implement a custom template, this is highly over-kill.

But the best way IMHO is to forget `/struts/js/foo.js` & use any other URL to load the js.

Few Samples :

**JSP**

```
WebPages
    |-->myjs.js         (a normal js file)
    |-->mydynamicjs.jsp (a .jsp file containing ONLY javascript code)
    |-->WEB-INF-->xyz.js (another .js file but accessed only through action)
```

**Struts**

```
<action name="myacctionjs">
    <result>/WEB-INF/xyz.js</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Well, is there an easy way to make Struts serve my js at any other url?